# I'm getting weird loop behaviour after passing char instead int

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, do-while

I'm working on a `JavaRush Course` problem - <Fahrenheit/Celsius Converter>:

1. Ask user direction of conversion
2. Ask user a temperature
3. Convert and print out result temperature

I'm trying to break program on a separate methods to understand how to work with methods and how to pass variables (I'm beginner in programing)

this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FahrenheitCelsius {
    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("---< Fahrenheit / Celsius Converter >---");
        String direction = getDirection();
        int temperature = getTemperature(direction);
        getResult(direction, temperature);
        sc.close();
    }

    // let's get direction of conversion from user input
    static String getDirection() {
        String direction;
        do {
            System.out.print("Convert from F or C: ");
            direction = sc.nextLine();
        } while (!direction.equals("F") && !direction.equals("C"));
        return direction;
    }

    // let's get temperature from user
    static int getTemperature(String direction) {
        int temperature;
        System.out.print("temperature in " + direction + ": ");
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("temperature in " + direction + ": ");
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        temperature = sc.nextInt();
        return temperature;
    }

    // let's convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
    static int fahrenheitToCelsius(int temperatureF) {
        return (temperatureF - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }

    // let's convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
    static int celsiusToFahrenheit(int temperatureC) {
        return temperatureC * 9 / 5 + 32;
    }

    // let's get result using direction and temperature we got
    static void getResult(String direction, int temperature) {
        int result;
        if (direction.equals("F")) {
            result = fahrenheitToCelsius(temperature);
            System.out.println("result temperature: " + result + "C");
        } else {
            result = celsiusToFahrenheit(temperature);
            System.out.println("result temperature: " + result + "F");
        }
    }
}
```

But!!!

I'm trying to write `getTemperature` method using `do while` loop.
Like this:

```
    static int getTemperature(String direction) {
        int temperature;
        do {
            System.out.print("temperature in " + direction + ": ");
            sc.nextInt();
        } while (!sc.hasNextInt());
        temperature = sc.nextInt();
        return temperature;
    }
```

At first I used separate instances of Scanner inside each method. And I got `noSuchElementExeption` - if user unput `characters`

Then I got the idea that I dont have to close scanner in `getDirection` method.

Then I red some advices in Stackoverflow and created separate `static final` instance of Scanner and passed it into methods

And right now I'm getting - `infinite loop` if user types `characters` instead `integers`

I know that is some weird behaviour with Scanner and this `nextLine()` thing.

But can't get an idea how to make `getTemperature` using `do while` loop without this bug.

Thanks in advance guys.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `main()` method might contain:

```
System.out.println("---< Fahrenheit / Celsius Converter >---");
String direction = "";
// Use of the String#matches() method with a small Regular Expression.
// (?i)     Ignore Letter Case
// [FC]     Only allow the character q, or Q
while (!direction.matches("(?i)[q]")) {
    direction = getDirection();
    if (!direction.matches("(?i)[q]")) {
        int temperature = getTemperature(direction);
        printResult(direction, temperature);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The `getDirection()` method might look like:

```
// let's get direction of conversion from user input
public static String getDirection() {
    String direction = "";
    while (direction.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Enter temperature scale to convert:");
        System.out.println("  F) Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("  C) Celsius");
        System.out.println("  Q) Quit");
        System.out.print("Your choice: --> ");
        direction = sc.nextLine();
        if (direction.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            System.out.println("\nBye-Bye\n");
            break;
        }
        // Use of the String#matches() method with a small Regular Expression.
        // (?i)     Ignore Letter Case
        // [FC]     Only allow the characters F, f, C, or c (q is handled ahead of time)
        if (!direction.matches("(?i)[FC]")) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Temperature Scale Type (" + direction 
                             + ")! Must be F or C! Try again...\n");
            direction = "";
        }
    } 
    return direction;
}
```

The `getTemperature()` method might look like:

```
// let's get temperature from user
private static int getTemperature(String direction) {
    String temp = "";
    // 'Ternary Operators' used here
    String directString = (direction.equalsIgnoreCase("f") ? "Fahrenheit" : "Celsius");
    String otherDirectString = (direction.equalsIgnoreCase("f") ? "Celsius" : "Fahrenheit");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Convert a Temperature in " + directString + " to " + otherDirectString + ":");
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a temperature in " + directString + ": --> ");
        temp = sc.nextLine().trim();
        // Since you're working with integer for temperature...
        // Use of the String#matches() method with a small Regular Expression.
        // ("\\d+")   Must be a string representation of an Integer numerical 
        // value with 1 (or possibly) more digits.
        if (!temp.matches("\\d+")) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Temperature Supplied (" + temp + ")! Try Again..." );
            temp = "";
        }
    } while (temp.isEmpty());
    return Integer.valueOf(temp);
}
```

The `getResult()` name is changed to `printResult()` because that is all it is essentially doing. It's not really getting anything:

```
// let's get result using direction and temperature we got
static void printResult(String direction, int temperature) {
    // 'Ternary Operator' used here
    System.out.println("Converted temperature is : " 
            + (direction.toUpperCase().equals("F") 
                 ? fahrenheitToCelsius(temperature) + "C" 
                     : celsiusToFahrenheit(temperature) + "F"));
}
```

Other misc. methods remain the same:

```
// let's convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
public static int fahrenheitToCelsius(int temperatureF) {
    return (temperatureF - 32) * 5 / 9;
}

// let's convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
public static int celsiusToFahrenheit(int temperatureC) {
    return temperatureC * 9 / 5 + 32;
}
```

Read the comments in code. You will of course notice that there is use of the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method for validation along with various small [Regular Expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) which are explained in the comments.

You will also notice the use of [Ternary Operators](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/ternary-operator.html) to reduce the display of IF/ELSE statements.

Comment: I did not expect such a detailed answer.) For me, this is already the next level of design of the program structure. I will definitely put all these tips you gave me into practice. Thank you DevilsHnd so much for this information and links to related topics.